# Django post request is returning querydict instead of object id for model form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have the modelform

```
class CollectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Medicine_Name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Medicine.objects.all())
   
    class Meta:
        model = Medicine
        fields = ['Number_Of_Boxes', 'Last_Collected']

    def __init__(self, user = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        if user:
            self.fields['Medicine_Name'].queryset=Medicine.objects.filter(User_Associated=user)
```

And the view to handle the form:

```
def update(request, *args, **kwargs):
     

        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        qd = request.POST['chosen_medicine']
       
        instance = Medicine.objects.get(id=qd)    
        form = CollectionForm(request.POST,  instance=instance)
       
        if form.is_valid():                 
            instance = form.save(commit=False)                
            instance.save()
    else:
        form = CollectionForm() 
    context = {'form': form,
            'meds': Medicine.objects.filter(User_Associated=request.user),
    }

    return render(request, 'tracker/medicine_collection.html', context )
```

The template for the form is here:

```
<form method="POST" action = ''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="Medicine_Name">Medicine Name</label>
    <select class = "form-control" id = "Medicine_Name"  name = "chosen_medicine">
        {% for med in meds %}
          
            <option value = '{{med.auto_id}}'>{{ med.Medicine_Name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    
    </select>
           
    {{form.Number_Of_Boxes  }}
    
    {{form.Last_Collected }}
    
  
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

I am trying to get the id of the Medicine_Name which the user chooses from the dropdown list. To do this I have a POST request in my view to get the id. However, when submitting my form I get the error:

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['rrkPEpuZqxWQ9TS4lLMRDwAQ7xZAOUVZl8iHLVfZJ8gEfKundDMvDh9oWp42l1Jf'], 'chosen_medicine': ['1'], 'Number_Of_Boxes': ['3'], 'Last_Collected': ['03/16/2020']}>.
```

How can I make sure the POST request actually gets the ID, not a querydict which contains all the fields of my form?

Comment: The `request.POST` is catched by the `user` parameter.

Comment: So is the problem in my __init__ method inside the form? How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the constructor such that the positional parameters are still preserved:

```
class CollectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Medicine
        fields = ['Number_Of_Boxes', 'Last_Collected']

    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        if user:
            self.fields['Medicine_Name'].queryset=Medicine.objects.filter(
                User_Associated=user
            )
```

In the view you then pass the user as a named parameter:

```
def update(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        qd = request.POST['chosen_medicine']
        instance = Medicine.objects.get(id=qd)    
        form = CollectionForm(request.POST, instance=instance, user=request.user)
       
        if form.is_valid():                 
            instance = form.save()
    else:
        form = CollectionForm(user=request.user)
    context = {'form': form,
            'meds': Medicine.objects.filter(User_Associated=request.user),
    }
    return render(request, 'tracker/medicine_collection.html', context)
```

The HTML also looks "odd", especially the spacing around attributes:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="Medicine_Name">Medicine Name</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="Medicine_Name" name="chosen_medicine">
        {% for med in meds %}
            <option value="{{ med.id }}">{{ med.Medicine_Name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>    
    {{ form.Number_Of_Boxes  }}
    {{ form.Last_Collected }}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: I implemented your code, but I now get the error `Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.` So it is no longer posting the 'chosen_medicine' at all.

Comment: Then taht means your `chosen_medicine` from the HTML form did not return a value (well it returned the empty stringas value). But the form has nothing to do with that, so that is an error in the template. The spacing in the HTML also looks *odd* (if not invalid).

Comment: @Smasher640: shouldn't this be `med.id` as value by the way?

Comment: @Smasher640: note that it *does* post something, since otherwise it would raise a `KeyError`.

Comment: Ah, indeed - I changed it to `med.auto_id` in testing, but forgot to change it back. Even after reverting it to `med.id`, the HTML form returns an empty string. Could this be because 'Medicine_Name' is not included in my form fields (as you can see in my model form)?

Comment: @Smasher640: no, first of all it *does* submit a value for the given key, since otherwise it would raise a `KeyError`. The fact that the Django form does not contain (all) the fields, does not matter, since HTML does not know anything about how it was rendered/constructed. You should check if the HTML code generated is valid, and fix the template accordingly.

Comment: By the way, the whole original problem I had was that I needed to get the instance of my model based on what medicine the user selects in the dropdown menu. I then need to update this specific instance of my Medicine model. I could not find a natural way to do this.

Comment: @Smasher640: the `Medicine_Name` in the form does not make much sense, so you can remove that. Furthermore you should try to find out why it posts an empty string in the request body.

Comment: After cleaning up my HTML, it now posts the id correctly. Thank you for your suggestion to review my template. Now the problem is my form doesn't seem to be valid; the `form.is_valid()` check is failing, and data is not being saved.

Comment: @Smasher640: did you remove the `Medicine_Name=...`? If not, it will expect a value for that. You should remove this form field.

Comment: Excellent, it worked just as expected after doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Something quick and messy could work.

```
data = dict(qd.iterlists())
instance = Medicine.objects.get(id=int(data.get('chosen_medicine')[0]))
```

But in my opinion you should not even post a whole queryset if all you need is a single id.

Comment: Well, I need to post all the fields to process in my view, but I only need the id initially to define the instance. Is there a good way to separate them, without them getting posted together in a querydict?